# Filter only path of files (without directories path) from output using pipe |

Tags: files, find, grep, pipe

`rpm -qpl dhad-9.0.27891-2.x86_64.rpm` allows to display all file paths and directory paths of this package .

### Example of output :

```
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/lib/wine/winmm.dll.so
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/lib/wine/winspool.drv.so
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/lib/wine/winsta.dll.so
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/lib/wine/wintrust.dll.so
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/lib/wine/ws2_32.dll.so
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/lib/wine/wtsapi32.dll.so
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/coue1255.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/coue1256.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/coue1257.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/coure.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/couree.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/coureg.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/courer.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/couret.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/cvgasys.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/hvgasys.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/jsmalle.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/jvgasys.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/marlett.ttf
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/smae1255.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/smae1256.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/smae1257.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/smalle.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/smallee.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/smalleg.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/smaller.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/smallet.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/ssee1255.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/ssee1256.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/ssee1257.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/ssee874.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/ssef1255.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/ssef1256.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/ssef1257.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/ssef874.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sserife.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sserifee.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sserifeg.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sserifer.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sserifet.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sseriff.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sseriffe.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sseriffg.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sseriffr.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/sserifft.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/svgasys.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/symbol.ttf
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/tahoma.ttf
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/tahomabd.ttf
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/vgas1255.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/vgas1256.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/vgas1257.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/vgas874.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/vgasys.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/vgasyse.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/vgasysg.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/vgasysr.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/fonts/vgasyst.fon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/generic.ppd
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/l_intl.nls
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/wine/share/wine/wine.inf
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/LICENSE
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/README
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/xdg-desktop-icon
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/xdg-desktop-menu
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/xdg-email
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/xdg-icon-resource
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/xdg-mime
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/xdg-open
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/xdg-screensaver
/opt/dhad/tv_bin/xdg-utils/xdg-settings
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/viewer
/var
/var/log
/var/log/viewer
```

I want to **filter only file paths** :

i try :

```
rpm -qpl dhad-9.0.27891-2.x86_64.rpm | find -type f
```

Also :

```
rpm -qpl dhad-9.0.27891-2.x86_64.rpm|grep -f
```

Also :

```
rpm -qpl dhad-9.0.27891-2.x86_64.rpm |ls -f
```

All didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Well that was horrible. Provided the output is sorted like this though, we can look at it backwards:

1. Take the last line
2. Lop off anything after the last `/` and store it, and move on to the next line up
3. If the line *doesn't* equal the last directory name, print
4. Move up the output and go back to step 2.

To keep the order, we also need to re-reverse the output. Thankfully there's a little command called `tac` (the reverse of `cat`) to make this simple. We just call it before and after our Bash scripting:

```
... | tac | while read p; do [ "$l" != "$p" ] && echo "$p"; l="$(dirname "$p")"; done | tac
```

Note that this will only ever work if we can rely on the file order. I think we probably can; I've only ever seen package files sorted like this so I assume it's standard.

---

When trying to answer this, I started using a different method with `awk`. I seem to give most of my answers in `awk`-form these days so here's the above as seen by awk:

```
... | tac | awk 'l!=$0{print}{sub(/\/[^\/]*$/,"",$1);l=$0}' | tac
```

It's a little shorter but I doubt it's any faster.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like README and LICENSE are files. So you could try,

```
rpm -qpl dhad-9.0.27891-2.x86_64.rpm | grep -P '.*\..*|README|LICENSE'
```

Comment: As this is coming out the back of a `rpm` command, I don't think your second approach (testing the live filesystem) is neccessarily going to work. Assume all the paths only exist in the rpm file.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to *test* each file path I think e.g. something like

```
some command \
| xargs -I{} sh -c 'test -f "$0" && printf "%s\n" "$0"' {}
```

or

```
while read -r f; do 
  [[ -f "$f" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$f"
done < <(some command)
```

Comment: As I said to Avinash, this only works if the files exist in real life. We're querying an RPM here so it seems possible that they won't exist on the system.

Comment: Ah sorry - I haven't used RH in a while, I assumed `rpm -qpl` would be the equivalent of something like `dpkg -L` i.e. list the files belonging to an _installed_ package.

Comment: rpm -ql foo lists the files if foo is isntalled. rpm -qlp foo.rpm lists the files reading the data from the archive, foo.rpm . For such reasons, this question if probably asked in a .rpm support channel.